# var statement throwing error in react.js

Tags: reactjs

So im trying to create a counter to determine if a verticle bar should be rendered in my component but everytime I try to create the counter variable outside of the map function it throws an error:

```
return (
            <div className={css.classNames.div} style={css.styles.div}>
                {   var counter = [];
                    this.props.children.map(function(child){
                    counter.push('1')
                    if (counter.length !== this.props.children.length){
                        return <li className={css.classNames.list}>{child}</li>;

                    } else {
                        return <li className={css.classNames.list}>{child}</li>;
                    }

                }.bind(this))

            }
            </div>
        );
```

There must be a way to do it. Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: `{ ... }` can only include a single expression, not statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `var counter = [];` to before the `return`.

```
var counter = [];
return (
  <div className={css.classNames.div} style={css.styles.div}>
  {this.props.children.map(function(child){
     counter.push('1')
     if (counter.length !== this.props.children.length){
       return <li className={css.classNames.list}>{child}</li>;
     } else {
       return <li className={css.classNames.list}>{child}</li>;
     }
   }.bind(this))}
   </div>
);
```